# XAML popup overflow in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Popup that looks like this:

`<local:toolbox_popup x:Name="PopupBaseMapLayers" Grid.Row="1" StaysOpen="False" 
    PopupAnimation="Fade"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  AllowsTransparency="True" 
    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=tooldropdown}" PlacementRectangle="-280,0,0,0" >
    <StackPanel> 
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
    </SrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
    </local:toolbox_popup>`

So the Popup appears when the user clicks a button, but the popup overflows outside the window because of how long it is. Is there a way to either have the overflow hidden within the window or set the height of the popup to be dynamic with whatever the size of the window is?

Comment: If you want something constrained by the size of the parent, you don't want a Popup. Use something else. Maybe a Border around a StackPanel. Set Panel.ZIndex on it if you need to. Position it using Margin. Set its visibility with a trigger or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot many things needs to be considered in your question. What should be the minimum width which would be feasible, where exactly are the buttons which are used to show this `Popup`. Are these `Buttons` are at right bottom of the Window ?

Consider everything, I suggest following settings which will solve your problem.

```
<Popup x:Name="Popup1" Placement="Relative" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Grd}" StaysOpen="False"  Width="{Binding PlacementTarget.ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
...
</Popup>
```

Here I have set `PlacementTarget` to be the top most container `Grid`.   `StatysOpen = False` causes `Popup` to disappear if we click anywhere outside. You can even choose `Window` as your `PlacementTarget`.

Then there is another property called `PlacementRectangle` to place it, you can apply `Binding` with a `Converter` to return `Rectangle`.

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: yes this method seems to get it in the best position, but its still overlapping some elements and the z-index can't change in a popup. I might change from popup to grid and StackPanel just so I have more control over the z-index. But as far as this is concerned, it works quite well so thanks!

Comment: @Whirlwind991 Popup will always overlap elements.

Comment: Yes I thought I could get away with using a Popup but I may not be able to in the end. But the placement still works, so my question was answered which is the main thing

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN reference on [Popup Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018.aspx) a popup resizes according to content.

> By default, a Popup is automatically sized to its content. When
>   auto-sizing occurs, some bitmap effects may be hidden because the
>   default size of the screen area that is defined for the Popup content
>   does not provide enough space for the bitmap effects to display.
>
> Popup content can also be obscured when you set a RenderTransform on
>   the content. In this scenario, some content might be hidden if the
>   content of the transformed Popup extends beyond the area of the
>   original Popup. If a bitmap effect or transform requires more space,
>   you can define a margin around the Popup content in order to provide
>   more area for the control. Perhaps your Popup content is having sizing
>   issues due to you restricting growth within your layout container?
>   Your Popup is thus sized accordingly but your Grid for example may
>   have a fixed width.

Anyways you can try setting the width and height of popup according to its parent window in the popup constructor like this :

```
this.Height = Application.Current.MainWindow.Height;
this.Width = Application.Current.MainWindow.Width;
```